# SSLError when calling OpenAI

Tags: ssl, openai-api, langchain

I am running OpenAI with LangChain using FastAPI in Google Cloud Run. It runs correctly for some time, but after some calls, I start getting this error:

`WARNING - Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /v1/chat/completions"`

It tries to call the endpoint several times and then gives up.